# Objective-C Strange Method Declaration

Tags: objective-c, methods, method-declaration

I was recently looking at some old source code from another company's project and came across the following method definition:

`-(double)getDistance :Latitude :Longitude`

I understand what the method does, but I've never seen an Objective-C method declared like that...  Even if the incoming object's type was unknown, I would expect something more along these lines:

`- (double)getDistanceWithLatitude:(id)latitude longitude:(id)longitude`

Could somebody give me the nitty gritty details on exactly how `-(double)getDistance :Latitude :Longitude` "works"?

Comment: If omitted, the type defaults to `id`. You can do this with the return type as well.

Comment: Interesting...  It sure does look terrible though, especially when you don't include the return type.

Comment: Yes, it surely does, you should never do it. It's an ancient, obsolescent heritage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If omitted, the type defaults to `id`. You can do this with the return type as well. It looks horrible in my opinion, and it's not the clearest notation - you should typically avoid using it. It's an ancient, obsolescent heritage.

Comment: Aww, thanks for the edit. I was copy-pasting & typing quickly and not paying attention.